# Synology NAS, Synology Drive Sync - won't synchronize between central office and remote location

Tags: sync, nas, synology-diskstation

Our company has Synology NAS (DS1517+) at central office. We have the NAS device (DS1618+) at remote location (production site). It used to be syncing before, but then synchronization has gone, on production site NAS. Sometimes when I open Synology Drive Sync, it says that "Service is not enabled". Later on that message goes away, but synchronization is not occuring properly. Many files from central office won't get downloaded to remote location NAS

How do I identify a reason of this issue and get back to sync adequately?

Answer (score 0):

Due to frequent power shutdowns a Synology NAS is not synchronizing well. That's what I have observed.